# Warning Illegal String offset

Tags: php, string, warnings, offset

I have taken over a site and I am not a PHP professional.

I get the following message:

Illegal string offset 'item' in on line7 &  Illegal string offset 'label' in on line8

Here is the code from the file:

```
<?php if($menus = get_field('menu','header-general')):  ?>
<div class="menu menu--main desktop">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($menus as $menu): ?>
            <li class="submenu submenu--<?= $menu['acf_fc_layout']; ?>">
                <a href="<?= ($menu['item']['link'] != '') ? $menu['item']['link'] : '#'; ?>"><?= $menu['item']['label']; ?></a>
                <?= getHeaderMenu($menu, $menu['acf_fc_layout']); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Greetings Jan

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($menu)`. Error means that there is no such keys in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try var_dump($menus) for check $menus have a value or not